# OpenCV (Python): Watershed Markers for body parts measurement

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, watershed

What criteria and algorithm should be used to classify and measure various parts of the body like waist, hip, neck, chest, etc.
I am new to openCV(currently code in python) and I am working on a project requiring to measure the size of body parts given the height of the person, frontal and lateral images.

I have found something called Kollman's Distribution, which divides the entire body in 10 equal parts and in this way measures the sizes:

[image]

Do I need to use watershed algorithm for implementing it? If yes, how can I mark those 10 dividers using watershed algorithm and then how do I carry out measurements.

I found this article useful - [Human Body Modelling by Development of
the Automatic Landmarking Algorithm](https://www.kiv.zcu.cz/site/documents/verejne/vyzkum/publikace/technicke-zpravy/2012/tr-2012-11.pdf).

Comment: The starting point for achieving the desired results would be 1. Human body detection, using haar-cascades 2. Body Landmark detection which would label  the various joints, etc. ex: dlib. Now you have pre-requisites to follow along the attached PDF.

Comment: @ZdaR , Can you please describe how to detect body landmark using dlib since I can only find it for face detection. And how can that be useful for further analysis?

Comment: Dlib can't be used for body landmarks directly, but you can train your own model for detecting body parts in frontal and side pose separately,